# Add sequence number by group with constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a `Demo` table

```
CREATE TABLE `Demo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `seq` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `old_status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `new_status` int(11) NOT NULL
)
```

... and the demo data

```
INSERT INTO `Demo` (`id`, `seq`, `old_status`, `new_status`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 2),
(1, 2, 2, 3),
(1, 3, 3, 9),
(1, 4, 9, 2),
(1, 5, 2, 3),
(2, 1, 1, 2),
(2, 2, 2, 3);
```

`Demo` table look like

| id | seq | old_status | new_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 | 3 | 9 |
| 1 | 4 | 9 | 2 |
| 1 | 5 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 |

I want to add a column that hold the version by group with condition that if we meet the `new_status` = 9 then increase the previous by one by each group of `id`.
The expected results:

| id | seq | old_status | new_status | _version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 3 | 9 | 2 |
| 1 | 4 | 9 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 5 | 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 1 |

I have tried to use `LAG` function to get my result but something went wrong!

```
SELECT id, old_status, new_status, 
case 
    when new_status <> 9 then Lag(_version, 1) Over(PARTITION by id ORDER by seq) 
    else Lag(_version, 1) Over(PARTITION by id ORDER by seq) + 1
end _version
from 
(select id, old_status, new_status, 1 as _version, seq
from Demo
order by id, seq) result
```

How can I calculate `_version` directly on exists `_version` column or are there any another approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this from a computed column, but you can use `SUM()` here as an analytic function:

```sql
SELECT *, SUM(new_status = 9) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY seq) + 1 AS _version
FROM Demo
ORDER BY id, seq;
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution and that worked for me, can you explain a bit about how `SUM()` analytic function works?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't fully explain how window functions work in a comment or even an answer.  `SUM(new_status = 9)` counts the number of times the new status is 9 for each `id` group, ordered by the `seq`.